# Hook function in Linux SO file

Tags: dynamic-analysis, function-hooking

I'm working on reverse engineering an Android application where the native code opens TLS connections using a built-in copy of mbedtls with certificate pinning. I'd like to decrypt that traffic and log it.

Normally, I would use LD_PRELOAD. In this case I cannot because mbedtls is embedded in the same dynamic library it is being called from, so traditional PLT/GOT hookers won't do.

Comment: AFAIK https://frida.re/ should solve the problem

Comment: It doesn't, frida.re appears to use the same PLT/GOT hooking technique.

Comment: https://blog.quarkslab.com/when-sidechannelmarvels-meet-lief.html